# How to toggle a button in React and increment the number by 1 or -1

Tags: reactjs, react-toggle

I'm working on the like and dislikes Ratio button like youtube Concept (Unique vote), I want to click on the button and increase the value for like by 1 and decrement for dislike by -1. but when I click on my button the increment or the decrement keeps going.

i will share with you my code :

```
const SingleMovieCard = ({singleMovie : {id, title,image ,category, likes, dislikes}, removeMovie}) => {

    const [isLike, setIsLike] = useState(likes);
    const [isDislike, setIsDislike] = useState(dislikes);


    const likeMovie = () =>  setIsLike(isLike + 1);
    const dislikeMovie = () => setIsDislike(isDislike - 1) ;

    return (

        <section key={id} className="single-movie">
            <img src={image} alt={title}/>
            <footer>
                <div className="movie-info">
                    <h2 className="title">{title}</h2>
                    <h4 className="category">{category}</h4>
                </div>  
            

                <div className="ratio-section">
 
                    <div>
                    <i onClick={likeMovie} class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i>
                    <h5>{isLike}</h5>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div>
                    <i onClick={dislikeMovie} class="far fa-thumbs-down"></i>
                    <h5>{isDislike}</h5>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <button className="btn" onClick={()=> removeMovie(id)}>Delete </button>
                
            </footer>
            
        
        </section>
    )
}


export default SingleMovieCard;
```

Parents element of this component :

```
import React from 'react';
import SingleMovieCard from '../SingleMovieCard/SingleMovieCard';


const MoviesCards = ({moviesList, removeMovie}) => {
    return (
        <section>        
        <div className="grid-list">
        {moviesList.map((singleMovie)=>  {
        return(
            <SingleMovieCard singleMovie={singleMovie}
                             key={singleMovie.id}
                             removeMovie={removeMovie} />
        )
        })}

        </div>
        </section>
        
    )
}


export default MoviesCards;
```

This is the data :

```
export default [
    {
      id: '1',
      title: 'Oceans 8',
      image: 'https://i.ibb.co/8mt68ZB/wp3051367-oceans-8-wallpapers.jpg',
      category: 'Comedy',
      likes: 4,
      dislikes: 1
    }, 
    
    {
      id: '2',
      title: 'Midnight Sun',
      image:' https://i.ibb.co/sCZSNnv/3524235.jpg',
      category: 'Comedy',
      likes: 2,
      dislikes: 0
    }, {
      id: '3',
      title: 'Les indestructibles 2',
      image: 'https://i.ibb.co/M2d5Fnp/923701.jpg',
      category: 'Animation',
      likes: 3,
      dislikes: 1
    },
    ]
```

Comment: I am confused what you are trying to do

Comment: Sorry, I want to increase the number of likes that I already have in my data by 1 when I click on <i  class=" far fa-thumbs-up"></i> and and decrease it by 1 when i click on <i class="far fa-thumbs-down"></i>. just like the youtube likes and dislikes button.

Comment: Can you also add the parent of this componet

Comment: I shared the parent elements of this the child components and data :D . Thank you guys

Comment: Do you want an unique vote? A person like/dislike just once?

Comment: Yes a unique vote please

Comment: What do you mean by `when I click on my button the increment or the decrement keeps going.`?

Comment: when I click on the like button I want to increment the value by 1 (Just like youtube Likes and Dislikes) the same concept :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I understood your question you need Unique Vote

```
          const [likeCount setLike] = useState(likes);
          const [dislikeCount, setDislike] = useState(dislikes);

          const [likeState, setLikeState] = useState(false)
          const [dislikeState, setDislikeState] = useState(false)
          const [vote, setVote] = useState(false)

          const [isLike, setIsLike] = useState(0);
          const [isDislike, setIsDislike] = useState(0);


          const likeMovie = () => {
            if(!vote && !likeState) { 
              setLike(likeCount + 1);
                setLikeState(true)
                setVote(true)
            }
            if(vote && likeState) {  
              setLike(likeCount - 1);
                setLikeState(false)
                setVote(false)
            }
          
          } 

          const dislikeMovie = () => {
            if(!vote && !dislikeState) {
             
              setDislike(dislikeCount - 1);
                setDislikeState(true)
                setVote(true)

            }
            if(vote && dislikeState) {   
              setDislike(dislikeCount + 1);
                setDislikeState(false)
                setVote(false)
            }
          
          }
```

then

```
  <div>
            <i onClick={likeMovie} class="far fa-thumbs-up"></i>
            <h5>{likeCount}</h5>
            </div>
            
            <div>
            <i onClick={dislikeMovie} class="far fa-thumbs-down"></i>
            <h5>{dislikeCount}</h5>
            </div>
```